# how to set a Excel's sheet ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False use Python xlwings

Tags: python, excel, vba, xlwings

In Excel VBA I can use ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False to make sht.DisplayGridlines disappear.

In python xlwings I don't know how to do it.

There is my code:

```
import xlwings as xw

class MyExcel():
    """
    定义Excel类
    """

    def __init__(self, wb=None):
        if wb:
            self.wb = wb
        else:
            try：
                self.wb = xw.books.active
            except:
                print('不存在打开的工作簿')

        self.app = xw.App(visible=True, add_book=False)

    def sht(self, sht_name, clean = True, DisplayGridlines = False):
        try:
            return self.wb.sheets.add(name=sht_name, after=self.wb.sheets[-1].name)
        except ValueError:
            return self.wb.sheets[sht_name]

        if DisplayGridlines == False:
            self.wb.activate
            self.wb.sheets[sht_name].activate
            self.app.api.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False #wrong!!!

        if clean:
            self.wb.sheets[sht_name].cells.clear()


def main():
    sht = MyExcel().sht('a')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import xlwings as xw
app = xw.apps.active
app.api.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = True
app.api.ActiveWindow.DisplayGridlines = False
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run. [Reference](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)

Answer (score 0):

```
import win32com.client

excel = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
excel.visible = True
# wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(r'c:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\2019-11-25.xlsx')
excel.Windows[excel.Activeworkbook.name].DisplayGridlines = False
excel.Activeworkbook.save
excel.quit()
```

To solve the question using win32com package.

Comment: Where can I find more info the win32com api? For instance if I want to change the reference style?